# ERM model - ternary relationship with weak entity

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I have a simple database design. It has entities: `User` `Place` `Review`. Basically a user can post a place (location of some place) and a user can post a review. Right now i have a ternary relationship between the 3 to be able to post a review about a place by a user.

It's like 
`User` ---- `<post>` ---- `Review` 
and `Place` ---- `<post>` ---- `User`

So, it's a 3 way.

First of all is the correct usage? As in, can i do that? I don't really care if it's not the best way, I just want to know if that is legit?

Second, i made `Review` a weak entity, but how can I make it so it takes the primary key of User and the primary key of Places? If i make it a weak entity will it automatically accept both of their primary ids?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> First of all is the correct usage? As in, can i do that? I don't really care if it's not the best way, I just want to know if that is legit?

No to my eyes, as I see you connect place to itself in the 2nd relation. I assume it's a typo and you mean `User`----`<post>`----`Place`.

> Second, i made Review a weak entity, but how can I make it so it takes the primary key of User and the primary key of Places? If i make it a weak entity will it automatically accept both of their primary ids?

The requirement is missing a couple of important things, such as:

1. How many reviews can a user post about a place?
2. Can more than one user post the same place?
3. Can more than one user post review about the same place?

etc., so it's a bit difficult to give exact answer.

One example with the following assumptions:

1. A user could post many places
2. More than one user could post the same place
3. A user could post only one review for a place

You could create this relation:

```
User(m)--<post>--(n)Place
           |
           |
         Review
```

If you explain a bit more maybe I could lead you to the expected solution.

Comment: Yea, i fixed that portion about the place to place. But your model is what i was thinking. I did a user can post multiple places, but only post 1 review per place per user and only 1 place period. So another user could not post the same place again. So, basically your #2 in your assumption would be only 1 place can be posted by any user.

Comment: Well, that simplifies things a lot. So, Place now has User and Review as attribute. Done :)